# Mapbox GL JS: Show all labels completely inside non-interactive map

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl, mapbox-gl-js

Labels across the visble map's edges are only shown partially. This is of course expected behaviour and not a problem when panning is possible.

But for non-interactive maps, like in this [Mapbox example](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/interactive-false/), panning is disabled. There's no way for users to ever see those labels completely. That leaves most of them as useless clutter.

For this case, when panning is disabled, I'd prefer to either render those labels completely inside the visible map or not at all. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<strike>The [`symbol-avoid-edges` property](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/#layout-symbol-symbol-avoid-edges) provides the behaviour for which you're asking. Applying this property to all symbol layers in your base layer will require some light scripting or elbow grease.</strike>

There is no existing way to prevent labels from intersecting with the viewport edges.

Comment: Thank you, I'll give it a try tomorrow. I always thought that the edges of the visible map are not automatically vector tile edges as well and that it's these vector tile edges that `symbol-avoid-edges` refers to, the same edges shown when using `map.showTileBoundaries = true`? I would be very glad if someone could shed some light on these (mis?-)understandings of mine.

Comment: Yes you're right. The "edges" in `symbol-avoid-edges`  refers to tile edges not viewport edges. Retracting my answer. There is no existing way to avoid viewport edges.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Btw, if you'd post this as an answer and not a comment, I'd accept it as solving my question.